# how to locate n tiles to a grid - prolog

Tags: prolog, tile

I am trying to solve the ntiles problem which can be described like, we have a grid. Then we want to locate N tiles with given size to the grid. We have rule such as:

```
ntiles(A/B, Grid, N, Pos1/Pos2) :-
```

And it should return the possible positions which we can locate the tiles:

```
>ntiles(2/1,3,2,P).

P=[1/1,1/3]?;
P=[1/1,2/3]?;
P=[2/1,1/3]?;
P=[2/1,2/3]?;
No.
```

I think it is a simple recursive problem but I couldnt manage to solve it. First I tried to locate the tiles only on a single row starting with position 1/1. This means I am staying in first row only for now. I thought that, if I achieve this it is easy to implement it for columns.

You will  understand me when you check my code:

```
ntiles(A/B, G, N, K) :-
   setof(X/Y, horizontal(A/B, G, N, X/Y), K).

horizontal(A/B, G, N, P1/P2) :-
   N > 0,
   P is A + 2,
   P =< G,
   horizontal(A/B, G, N-1, P/1).
```

This codes returns 'false'. I expected to return it the list of K. Do you have an idea that where the problem is?

Also can you give me insight to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems.

The main is that setof/3 should be used to get all solutions, then require a goal of kind 'generate on backtrack', but horizontal/4 is coded instead as a deterministic list constructor.

Other problems are:

- horizontal/4 will succeed only when N > 0. What about the base case (i.e. N *is* 0) ?
- P1,P2 are *singletons*: they cannot play any role in your solution.
- Arithmetic must be evaluated explicitly, then instead of passing N-1 you should add - for instance - `M is N-1`, and pass M in the recursive call.

You could be interested to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16981889/874024) I gave on a (very) similar problem.